# Pundit no marca errores pero tampoco hace lo que debe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

He leido en varios foros la forma en la que pueda utilizar pundit para crear un modulo de ACL y todo mundo comenta que es sencillo de utilizar pero es la fecha que no puedo solucionar mi problema.

Basicamente tengo esto

1.- Agregue la gema `gem 'pundit'`

2.- Ejecute `bundle install`

3.- Agregue la siguiente línea en mi application_controller.rb `include Pundit`

4.- Antes de proseguir comento que tengo un namespace, por ejemplo

```
namespace :tg do
    resources :client_has_rooms
end
```

5.- Mi política por lo tanto la tengo en `app/policies/tg/client_has_room_policy.rb` y este es su código

```
class Tg::ClientHasRoomPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :client_has_room

    def initialize(user, client_has_room)
        @user = user
        @chr = client_has_room
    end

    def index?
        false
    end

    def update?
        if user.admin?
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end
end
```

He declarado el método index y en false, y en el método update el rol `admin` no existe, solo para probar y que no me permita actualizar la base de datos, de hecho estos son los roles que manejo, adjunto el código de mi modelo usuario

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum role: [:No, :Reservaciones, :Ventas, :Contabilidad, :Jefe, :Administrador]

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    def active_for_authentication?
        super && role != 'No'
    end

    after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
        def set_default_role
        self.role ||= :No
    end
end
```

No se como empezar, ni por donde buscar, pues no me marca ningún error, pero por ejemplo si en el sistema estoy logueado con el role de `Ventas`, me permite hacer todas las opciones, cuando claramente en mi política para `ClientHasRoom` tengo definido que solo el usuario "admin" puede actualizar.

Agradeceria la ayuda

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con la gema pundit, pero un error típico en el que caemos todos muchas veces es el de añadir una gema al `Gemfile`, hacer el `bundle`, pero después nos olvidamos de reiniciar el `rails server`. ¿A lo mejor esta ha podido ser tu caso?

Comment: No amigo, tristemente no fue mi caso u.u, lamentablemente nadie me contesto, asi que lo que hice fue utilizar pundit sin el namespace, esto me genera un poco de ruido porque no me gusta tener todo en una sola carpeta, pero tengo mas prisa que hacer que se vea ordenado asi que esa fue mi triste solucion a mi problema T_T

Comment: Hmmm, si es un problema que se soluciona al quitar el namespacing entonces el problema puede ser que rails no esté buscando en las carpetas adecuadas. Prueba a añadir esto en tu `config/application.rb` lo siguiente:
`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/policies/**/*"]`. Otra cosa necesaria para que funcione bien el namespacing es que tendrías que tener un archivo `app/policies/tg.rb` que declare un nuevo modulo:
`module Tg; end`

Comment: Si eso de `module Tg` y `Class Tg:policy` si lo intente, lo que no fue, probar agregando el path de polices a mi application.rb, lo cual acabo de probar y tampoco funciona u.u, he encontrado una referencia y aparentemente hay algunos problemas utilizando namespaces con pundit [https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/132], gracias de cualquier forma :D